# switch statement is not working. C#

Tags: c#

I run my code but when it goes in switch statement it does not execute it and goes out from program.
In switch statement when user press 1 it will go for addition , 2 for subtraction and so on.
I can't understand the error.

```
int c; c = 0;
int a;
int b;

Console.Write Line("Enter First Number");
a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.Read Line());
Console.Write Line("Enter First Number");
b = Convert.ToInt16(Console.Read Line());
Program k = new Program();
k.display();
switch(c)
{
    case 1 :
    {
        Console.Write Line("Answer is {0}",k.add(a,b));
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        Console.Write Line("Answer is {0}", k.sub(a,b));
    }
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        Console.Write Line("Answer is {0}", k.prod(a, b));
    }
        break;
    case 4 :
    {
        Console.Write Line("Answer is {0}", k.divide(a, b));
    }
        break;
    default:
        {
            Console.Write Line("Enter Valid value");
        }
        break;
}
    Console.Read Key();
}


public void display()
{
    Console.Write Line("Menu");
    Console.Write Line("1.Add");
    Console.Write Line("2.Subtract");
    Console.Write Line("3.Multiply");
    Console.Write Line("4.Divide");
    Console.Write Line("5.Modulus");
}
public int add(int x, int y)
{
    int sum;
    sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}

public int sub(int x, int y)
{
    int subtract;
    subtract = x - y;
    return subtract;
}

public int prod(int x, int y)
{
    int p;
    p = x * y;
    return p;
}

public int divide(int x, int y)
{
    int div;
    div = x / y;
    return div;
}
```

Comment: You have to ask for 'c' value. Always is 0

Comment: You have set `c = 0;` but not changed it's value. Therefore none of your switch cases will fire.

Comment: `switch statement is not working` this a known bug of c# :))

Comment: @Eser what do you mean this is a known bug in C#? the issue obviously before my edit to his code was that the `break` was outside of the each individual `case` statement

Comment: _"Microsoft issues huge product recall....news at 7!"_

Comment: @MethodMan He was making a joke. Obviously if the statement `switch statement is not working` was true, then one of the thousands (millions?) of C# developers would have caught it by now. Hence the irony of the statement.

Answer (score 4):

You're not putting a value in c

Add in the following code to do that:

```
Console.WriteLine("1 = Add, 2 = Subtract, 3 = Multiply, 4 = Divide");
c = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
```

Also your break statements needs to be inside your brackets:

```
case 1 :
{
    Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}",k.add(a,b));
    break;
}
```

And your `Write Line` and `Read Line` statements need to be turned into single words `WriteLine` and `ReadLine`

This code really is a mess. Are you writing it in Microsoft Word or something?

Comment: `Write Line` `Read Line` ?

Comment: I just copied the [incorrect] examples in@Syed's sample code. I've accepted the edit.

Comment: @DerekTomes what you have is correct but look at the switch statement carefully.. it will always break; no matter what number you enter because the break is outside the individual case statements

Comment: Gosh it is a mess isn't it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your variable `c`. It is alway zero when code goes through. You need to use your variable `c` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

when do you ever expect it to hit the second case statement when the `break` in your original code was outside the `case`

```
switch(c)
{
    case 1 :
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}",k.add(a,b));
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}", k.sub(a,b));
    }
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Answer is {0}", k.prod(a, b));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to do the operation you need to let user give input. I have pasted your code below. `variable c` is declared but user have never fed any input; it is always 0.

```
int c = 0;
int a;
int b;

Console.Write Line("Enter First Number");
a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.Read Line());
Console.Write Line("Enter First Number");
b = Convert.ToInt16(Console.Read Line());
Program k = new Program();
k.display();
switch(c)
```

You are not asking user to feed input for variable `int c`.

You can do something like below:

```
Program k = new Program();
k.display(); // Once it displays
c = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
switch(c)
{ /*your code*/ }
```